# File named 'undefined' returned in api response, spring boot

Tags: java, excel, spring, rest, spring-boot

I am facing a weird issue, I am trying to return an excel file (.xlsx) in the response of an api endpoint and the file returned is perfectly fine except the name of the file which is always coming as 'undefined.xlsx'.

The api is working fine in the postman ( i.e. filename is coming as expected) but when the same api is called via browser ( i.e my application) the filename of the returned file is 'undefined.xlsx'.
The file in both of the above cases is totally fine i.e. all the data, styles etc are as expected.

The both headers "Content-disposition" and "Content-Type" are visible in the response headers as well.

Please let me know if there's anything else required from my end.

Thanks a lot.

I've tried the following methods/ways to send the file :

  1.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "exportLogs/{deploymentId}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> exportDeploymentLogs(@PathVariable String deploymentId) throws IOException {
        File workbook = myService.exportLogs(deploymentId);
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=%s.xlsx",
                Utils.getFileName(workbook.getName())));
        httpHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(workbook), httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

2.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "exportLogs/{deploymentId}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> exportDeploymentLogs(@PathVariable String deploymentId) throws IOException {
        File workbook = myService.exportLogs(deploymentId);
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=%s.xlsx",
                Utils.getFileName(workbook.getName())));
        httpHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(workbook), httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

3.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "exportLogs/{deploymentId}")
    public Response exportDeploymentLogs(@PathVariable String deploymentId) throws IOException {
        File workbook = myService.exportLogs(deploymentId);
Response.ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.ok(workbook);
        responseBuilder.header("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=%s.xlsx",
                Utils.getFileName(workbook.getName())));
        responseBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
        return responseBuilder.build();
    }
```

4.

```
@POST
    @RequestMapping(value = "exportLogs2/{deploymentId}")
    public void exportDeploymentLogs2(@PathVariable String deploymentId,  HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        File workbook = myService.exportLogs(deploymentId);
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Utils.getFileName(workbook.getName())+".xlsx");
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        IOUtils.copy(FileUtils.openInputStream(workbook), response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
```

**Code -->**

API endpoint :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "exportLogs/{deploymentId}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> exportDeploymentLogs(@PathVariable String deploymentId) throws IOException {
        File workbook = myService.exportLogs(deploymentId);
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.add("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=%s.xlsx",
                Utils.getFileName(workbook.getName())));
        httpHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(workbook), httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

MyService:

```
public File exportLogs(String deploymentId){
  DeploymentDetail dt = deployService.getDeploymentById(deploymentId);
  XSSFWorkbook workbook = excelService.createExcel(dt);//which will create and update some data in file.
  try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                workbook.write(byteArrayOutputStream);
                return renameFile(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), fileName);
            }catch (Exception e){
                LOGGER.info("Error occurred while writing into stream {}", e);
                return File.createTempFile("Error", "xlsx");
            }
}
/*Although I can send the byte[] of workbook directly but thought that * there might be some problem in the workbook because of which the name * of the workbook is not showing, that's why I am creating a temp file 
* with the requestedName and sending this file back.
*/
private File renameFile(byte[] workbook, String fileName) throws IOException {
        File file = File.createTempFile(fileName, "xlsx");
        FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, workbook);
        return file;
    }
```

Expected - valid file with expected fileName.
Actual Output - valid file with 'undefined.xlsx' name.

Comment: It would not be wrong to do URL encoding `("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=%s.xlsx",
                URLEncoder.encodeURL(Utils.getFileName(workbook.getName())), "UTF-8"));`. But the error: "undefined" reeks of an **undefined JavaScript variable**. Ajax?

Comment: @JoopEggen : Thanks for the comment. I tried this but didn't work